# US citizen travelling to the UK with an immigration hiccup in the past

Tags: us-citizens, visa-free-entry, standard-visitor-visas, removal

I am a US citizen currently living in France with a long-term researcher visa. In the next year, I need to visit the UK for the following purposes:

- A week-long meeting / informal training with collaborators at a UK university. [My question here is whether this would be classed as work...]
- Giving a talk at a UK scientific society in order to accept an award I have been given, in May.
- A week-long conference in June. I'd like to travel for a few days longer to visit my old city/friends, but only if I'm allowed to.

As a US citizen I can enter the country visa-free on discretion of the border agent. However, this is complicated by the fact that I lived in the UK as a student from 2010 to 2015. I had a problem upon returning to the UK after visiting my family in June 2015, because the date of my graduation had passed (it was less than a week before I made a visit home). My visa was valid until October (they give students an extra few months after graduation to get their affairs in order), so I assumed I was within my rights to come back, pack my stuff, get my French visa and move, but they told me that it was no longer valid since I had already graduated.

I had been planning to pack my things and move to France, as I had already accepted my position by then, and I was currently waiting for my French visa to be validated (moving directly from GB to FR is a lot less expensive than going by way of the US). I was detained for a few hours, and the only reason I was let into the country was because I showed them the offer for my French position which convinced them that I had sufficient motivation to leave the UK. I was told to be out of the country by the end of the temporary leave they issued (the ending date was in January 2016, and I left in October 2015).

I understand that the leave to enter can allow for multiple entries into the UK over the course of six months, provided that the visa holder does not exceed 180 days per year or do illegal things, such as working. None of my visits will be longer than 1½ weeks, but they will be spread out over the course of the six months mentioned. I am worried that the UK Immigration folks will wonder if I'm secretly living in the UK given the frequency of the visits, even if they are short visits.

Can I enter the UK under this ruleset for these visits again, or will I have a problem with this since I entered under that same program in June 2015?

Meaning: Would it be a better idea to apply for a formal visa for my visits?

If I can enter visa-free again, will the fact that I have no exit stamp from October 2015 (I moved via a lorry using the ferry, and there was NO passport control from Dover to Calais; trust me, I ran around looking for somebody to stamp me for ages) present an issue?

(To clarify, my passport was taken by the ferry operator, but I was told there would be no stamp on the UK side and there was zero French Immigration monitoring in Calais)?

I have a Schengen visa and a French residence permit, but since the UK isn't Schengen, I know that is useless.

I'm worried about the UK government assuming that I've overstayed since they will obviously have no record of me leaving. I have my ferry ticket receipt, but not sure if that's anything they'd care about.

Should I be applying for a standard visitor visa instead?

If so, for how long?

Does casual training with collaborators in their university count as 'work'?

Comment: Small nitpicks: VWP is an American thing and the UK is different, the UK operates a visa-national regime.  Also, "...does not exceed 180 days per year..." is not accurate.  There's questions about that in our archives. And in all honesty, your question is asking for people's opinions about what to do; there's no *precise* answer to your question.

Comment: Was your passport not stamped when you entered france?

Comment: No, because I moved from the UK in the van with my mover, and when we got to the ferry, there was no passport control.

Comment: @GayotFow Oops, you're correct. Do you know what the correct terminology is? Just 'entry clearance' I guess, and I'll edit my post

Comment: @lafemmecosmique, 'standard-visitor-visa' is fine, it is a type of entry clearance; instead of VWP you can use 'leave-to-enter', 'visa-on-arrival', or to be rigorously correct 'Appendix V of the Immigration Rules' (https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules).  But you're still looking for an opinion poll, please get a laser-like focus on your question and I can vote to reopen it -- thanks!

Comment: Where you wrote "enter the UK under the VWP" it would be correct to write "enter the UK without a visa" etc.

Comment: When you got onto the ferry, the ferry operator should have asked for your passport and scanned it. They then send the relevant data to UKBA. Also, did you not get checked by french immigration? Did you keep the ferry's ticket? Do you have documents establishing your presence in France (signed lease, first utility bills, employment contract)?

Comment: Our passports were taken in a queue outside the docks, but the ferry op said I couldn't get an exit stamp from him (this was in the freight lane, as I was riding in the moving van, if it make a difference). But he did take our passports, I just didn't know that it was then recorded by UKBA at that point. That's great. And I do have a copy of the ferry ticket, and all of the other documents you listed. There was zero French immigration on the other side, but they knew I was here when I applied for my residence permit.

Comment: @GayotFow I have edited my question to get rid of references to VWP. I understand the difficulty in this being 'opinion based' as the UK rules in this regard are not exact and are much up to the discretion of the border agent. Do you have any suggestions as to how I can collimate my questions here? Mostly it's down to a) Does the past situation constitute a visa refusal, as that implies I will be refused leave to visit without a visa and b) does informal training count as working. I know already that there is no 'set' limit to visit frequency, annoyingly.

Comment: @lafemmecosmique you can ask something like "what advantages does an entry clearance provide in this type of situation". And don't forget to edit your title :) you can ping me when it's ready

Comment: Border control at Dover and Calais is juxtaposed; you are meant to clear French immigration in Dover, and UK immigration in Calais on the return. I am not sure how you managed to not see a French immigration official.

Comment: Did you manage to travel to the US?

Comment: If you mean the UK ;) then yes, I did. I arrived for the conference at the same time as several thousand others and it was fine. I am travelling again in December, hoping that will also be fine. @JonathanReez

Answer (score 2):

A reply from OP:

> If you mean the UK ;) Then yes, I did. I arrived for the conference at the same time as several thousand others and **it was fine**. I am travelling again in December, hoping that will also be fine.